# 50/50 Sampling in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sampling

I have a data set with a binary target variable that has a 4/96 percent split. I want to create a subset of the data with a 50/50 split. I would like to know the best way to do that in Python. Thanks!

Comment: Surely this depends on how large a sample you want? Do you want the sample to be as large as possible, or do you want it to be a fixed size? If your question is "how large a sample *should* I want", then there is no universal answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby()` your binary variable, then sample from each group.

Generate some random data:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'variable': ''.join(random.sample('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 4)), 'outcome': (random.random() > .94)} for i in range(100)])

>>> print(df)
    outcome variable
0     False     irlk
1     False     ylmp
2     True      przk
3     False     xldf
4     False     oxsp
5     False     uytn
6     False     ifmw
7     True      lepa
8     False     zfvm
...
99    False     qjek
100   False     umtw
```

Sample as needed:

```
>>> num_samples = 3
>>> df.groupby('outcome').apply(lambda x: x.sample(num_samples))
            outcome variable
outcome                     
False   71    False     jdrp
        98    False     eqrj
        78    False     tnzl
True    29     True     uvjr
        36     True     tiwn
        63     True     tabr
```

Answer (score 0):

The general answer (not hard-wired to the 4/96 split) is to partition the data in two groups (the 0 group and the 1 group), and then sample as many as needed from each partition.  (The technique is called "[stratified random sampling](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/032615/what-are-some-examples-stratified-random-sampling.asp)").

```
# Partition based on the target variable
group0 = [record for record in data if not record.target_variable]
group1 = [record for record in data if record.target_variable]

# Pick as many as needed from each partition
subgroup0 = random.sample(group0, k=4) 
subgroup1 = random.sample(group1, k=4)

# Combine and shuffle the results
combined = subgroup0 + subgroup1
random.shuffle(combined)
```